If u(x,y) = 3x - 2y + 5, how must v(x,y) be defined if u(x,y) + iv (x,y) is to be conformal?
I tried to solved this problem. From what I understood for u(x,y) + iv (x,y) to be conformal, it needs to satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations, and the diverative to be non zero.
So becuase ∂u/∂x=3 and ∂u/∂y=-2, and from Cauchy-Riemann equations which says:
∂u/∂x=∂v∂y & ∂u/∂x=-∂v/∂x,
I got that v(x,y) needs to be defined as 3y+2x+C.
But, in the answers it states that the answer is 3y-2x+C.
I can't understand why?

You are right and the given answer is wrong.

-Josè. That's good to hear, but are you 100% certain? Becuase the answer is from MIT open course, which is very doubtful to be wrong, but of course possible. So you certain?

Consider your answer: $v(x,y)=3y+2x+C$. Then\begin{align}u(x,y)+v(x,y)i&=3x-2y+5+(3y+2x+C)i\&=3(x+yi)+2i(x+yi)+5+Ci,\end{align}which is a conformal map; it's the map $z\mapsto(3+2i)z+5+Ci$. This shows that your answer is correct.
